# Add Constraints programmatically to ViewControllerCells

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

Creating a "Card-style" menu with CollectionViewCells and I need the cells to have the same space between |------| in any Screen size.

I was able to get to this point:

```
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-15-[v0]-15-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": appsCollectionView]))

addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": appsCollectionView]))
```

Where I've set the margins to 15 on each side of the screen, but whenever i load the app on a bigger screen, the space in between changes also.

I've tried to use :

```
appsCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

But I get this Log:

```
2016-12-07 16:51:14.902586 AppStoreClone[8843:206635] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000283fc0 H:[UICollectionView:0x7f8172010200]-(15)-|   (active, names: '|':AppStoreClone.CategoryCell:0x7f8173309710 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000284100 H:[AppStoreClone.CategoryCell:0x7f8173309710]-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7f8172010200]   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000284100 H:[AppStoreClone.CategoryCell:0x7f8173309710]-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x7f8172010200]   (active)>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your controls in a Stack View and implement Auto Layout.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html